# .Net Core 3.1 Adding identity to existing project with MySql

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with a MySql database and Entity Framework Core. I need to add identity to this project.

I've added this packages:

- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore

I've created an `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
 {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
 }
```

And add following code to the `Startup` file in the `ConfigurateServices` method:

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>  
            options.UseMySql(  
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)  
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Also I added a `DefaultConnection` to `appsetings.json`.

The last step in all tutorials is to recreate Migrations and here I got an error.

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Web'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

And If I run 'Enable-Migrations' I get

> No context type was found in the assembly 'Web'

How could I run migrations and update database?

Answer (score 8):

Create your User model (ApplicationUser) then inherent from IdentityUser

add your newly created user model as a generic argument to IdentityDbcontext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
 {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        
         protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
 }


services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)  
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Your User model should look like this.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

The last thing is for you to create and run a new migration to update your database

Note: If you have multiple DbContext in your project you need to specify the DbContext to use when creating the migration

for example here I've two different DbContext

```
dotnet ef migrations add {migration-name} -c TenantDbContext -s ../AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api/AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api.csproj to run the migration against a client.


dotnet ef database update -c GlobalDbContext -s ../AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api/AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api.csproj to run migration against the global context

dotnet ef migrations add {tenant-migration-name} -o Migrations/Tenants -c TenantDbContext -s ../AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api/AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api.csproj

dotnet ef database update -c GlobalDbContext -s ../AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api/AspNetCorePropertyPro.Api.csproj to run migration against the global context

-o = output directory.

-c = dbcontext to perform the migration if more than one exists.

-s = the path to the startup project.
```

Comment: As I said above, the actual problem is with calling a migration

Comment: can i see your project structure including where your DbContext is placed.

Comment: You can run your migration from the  project containing ApplicationDbContext 

dotnet ef migrations add {migration-name} -s {path to your startup project}

Comment: Project contains ApplicationDdContext, but I can't run migrations with the error described in the post.

Comment: @Samuel without exposing the entity type on a DbSet property how are entity types mapped to a table?

Comment: @Samuel or are you supposed to use the fluentAPI to do the mapping of entity types to database objects?

Comment: @starboy I feel it more elegant to used fluent way in describing  my tables instead of  data annotations. Please for any one that wants to see sample code, refer to https://github.com/SamuelKoroh/AspNetCorePropertyPro there you will see how everything is structured.